# CSS file won't link to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I recently decided to become a web developer and I started learning HTML and CSS but, I don't know why my CSS file won't link to my HTML file. My HTML file is in ~/Desktop/WebDev/HTML/ and my CSS file is in ~/Desktop/WebDev/CSS/. This is the code I used for my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/style.css">
        <title>My Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
        <p class="myParagraph">
            Hello! This is my website which I will try to develop over my journey into becoming a web developer.
            I really don't know what to say so...Goodbye!
        </p>
        <hr>
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>
        <a href="mailto:">Send Mail</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS file:

```
body{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

I honestly don't know why my CSS file won't link. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: `F12` to open your developer console, go to the network tab, and see what fully qualified path it is trying to find the css file on.  Given that we do not know where on your environment that file is actually located, you will have to check to see if that path is accurate.

Comment: ./CSS/style.css so it goes one folder behind, or ../CSS/style.css

Comment: `/` is root, `./` is same directory, `../` is one directory up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css">`instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/style.css">`

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I have a question though, why do I have to put the two dots in front? I'm just trying to understand so I don't make the same mistake anymore. Again, thanks!

Comment: NP! Because in this way from where you are (HTML folder) you move in the parent folder (WebDev) and then into CSS

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks again. I understand now. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can try ../CSS/style.css
You need to move in the parent folder before

Comment: I tried it but it still won't work.

Answer (score -1):

How do you know your css file hasn't linked? Did you hard refresh the page first to check?

Also change

- `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/style.css">` TO
- `<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="/CSS/style.css">`